Pyotp Microsoft Authenticator not displaying Logo after Scanning QR
I am using Pyotp python package to generate OTP's using python, the generated QR is perfectly working fine, Microsoft authenticator can add the required information and code matches as expected the only problem I am facing is the added image is not displaying in logo, the logo always consists of character initials.
The python code is following.
import pyotp
totp = pyotp.TOTP("secret")
uri = totp.provisioning_uri(name='User', issuer_name='Example', image='https://ecoedgeai.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/cropped-eeai-logo-1-95x54.png')
print(uri)

The example generated URI is following.
otpauth://totp/Example:User?secret=secret&issuer=Example&image=https%3A%2F%2Fecoedgeai.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2024%2F02%2Fcropped-eeai-logo-1-95x54.png

The image URL is valid and accessible in browser no restrictions on the URL so why Authenticator is not displaying logo? by the way I haven't tested it with other Authenticator applications.
